# Need running node in a file (getting a throw err) Express, Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, npm, node-modules

I need a solution please:

I'm new into node and express. I try to run my server.js file , but as soon as i do that i get this error.

[image: error message]

It's saying im on the wrong path but I'm not. Take a look here:

[image: IDE view]

The path is right because when i remove everything from my server.js and just log a statement for example console.log("Starting") and then running the node again on that file, it's working.

Take a look here:

[image: its working here...]

I think its a different problem? My main goal is to get the app from my app from my app.js file. Maybe i do something wrong? Here is another pic from Express file called app.js:

[image: app.js file]

Thank you :)

It should run the server.js file w/ out any errors

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load your own module, so you have to put a "./" before the actual path.

```
let app = require("./backend/app.js");
```

For other modules that you install via npm you should use only the module name in the require function

```
const express = require("express");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out, also don't work

[image]

Comment: If the server.js file (the file where you are trying to include the app module) is in the src directory you should specify the complete relative path from src like: ./../backend/app.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).